# Gaussian in pascal

Tags: java, logging, random, pascal, gaussian

I tried porting the code directly from the java source code to pascal, however it is throwing a run time error.

How can I get a proper Gaussian curve? What about pascals built in functions?

Original source code:

```
    synchronized public double nextGaussian() {
    // See Knuth, ACP, Section 3.4.1 Algorithm C.
    if (haveNextNextGaussian) {
        haveNextNextGaussian = false;
        return nextNextGaussian;
    } else {
        double v1, v2, s;
        do {
            v1 = 2 * nextDouble() - 1; // between -1 and 1
            v2 = 2 * nextDouble() - 1; // between -1 and 1
            s = v1 * v1 + v2 * v2;
        } while (s >= 1 || s == 0);
        double multiplier = StrictMath.sqrt(-2 * StrictMath.log(s)/s);
        nextNextGaussian = v2 * multiplier;
        haveNextNextGaussian = true;
        return v1 * multiplier;
    }
}
```

First attempt at pascal port (throws runtime error):

```
  function log (n : double) : double; 
  begin 
    result := ln(n) / ln(10); 
  end; 

  var hgauss : boolean;
  var ngauss : double;

  function gauss() : double;
  var x1, x2, w : double;
  begin
    if hgauss then
    begin
      result := ngauss;
      hgauss := false;
    end else
    begin
      repeat
        x1 := 2.0 * rand() - 1.0;
        x2 := 2.0 * rand() - 1.0;
        w := x1 * x1 + x2 * x2;
      until w >= 1.0;         

      w := sqrt( (-2.0 * log( w ) ) / w );
      result := x1 * w;
      ngauss := x2 * w;
      hgauss := true;
    end;
  end;
```

Invalid floating point operation here:

```
w := sqrt((-2.0 * log( w ) ) / w);
```

Second attempt at conversion (runs but I am not sure the math is correct):

```
  function log (n : double) : double; 
  begin 
    result := ln(n) / ln(10); 
  end; 

  var hgauss : boolean;
  var ngauss : double;

  function gauss() : double;
  var x1, x2, w, num : double;
  begin
    if hgauss then
    begin
      result := ngauss;
      hgauss := false;
    end else
    begin
      repeat
        x1 := 2.0 * rand() - 1.0;
        x2 := 2.0 * rand() - 1.0;
        w := x1 * x1 + x2 * x2;
      until w >= 1.0;         

      num := -2.0 * log( w )  / w;
      w := sqrt(abs(num));
      if num < 0 then w := -w;
      result := x1 * w;
      ngauss := x2 * w;
      hgauss := true;
    end;
  end;
```

Comment: Which pascal compiler are you using? How does the java handle divide by 0? . You need to handle it in your pascal. You are also neglecting the case when w = 0 in your repeat loop, (s == 0 in your java)

Comment: I am using SCAR DIVI 3.41. As far as I know, Java does not allow divide by zero, so I think the compilers should be handling it the same. There is also a function called RandG() which supposedly returns a "gaussian" but it does not appear to be in the normal distribution.

Comment: If you code in Free Pascal you may also use the [randg](http://lazarus-ccr.sourceforge.net/docs/rtl/math/randg.html) function to get Gaussian random numbers. See http://wiki.freepascal.org/Generating_Random_Numbers for more information on how to generate random numbers from a large number of different distributions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `rand()` is in `[0,1)` range ( `0 <= rand() < 1` )
so `2.0 * rand() - 1.0` is in `[-1,1)` range
so `x1` and `x2` are in `[-1,1)` range
so `w := x1 * x1 + x2 * x2` is in `[0,2)` range

and in `sqrt( -2.0 * ln( w ) / w )` the `w` is positive
so the natural logarithm: ln(w) should be negative
so w should be in `(0,1)` range
so  that loop should not exit `until (w > 0.0)and (w < 1.0);`

working sample code (using SCAR Divi 3.41.00):

```
program New; 

 var hgauss : boolean;
 var ngauss : double;

  function gauss() : double;
  var x1, x2, w : double;
  begin
    if hgauss then
    begin
      result := ngauss;
      hgauss := false;
    end else
    begin
      repeat
        x1 := 2.0 * rand() - 1.0;
        x2 := 2.0 * rand() - 1.0;
        w := x1 * x1 + x2 * x2;
      until (w > 0.0)and (w < 1.0);   
      w := sqrt( -2.0 * ln( w ) / w );
      result := x1 * w;
      ngauss := x2 * w;
      hgauss := true;
    end;
  end;

begin
  writeln( gauss() );
  writeln( gauss() );
end.
```

Answer (score 3):

Your port from Java to Pascal is faulty for an important part

`do {...} while (s >= 1 || s == 0);`

should be translated to

`repeat {...} until ((s<1) and (s<>0));`

So you have the wrong terminating condition. Java terminates the loop if `0 < s < 1`, but your loop is finished if `w >= 1`.

If `w > 1` you have `-2*ln(w) < 0` and the floating point exception comes from taking a square root of a negative number!

And for most Pascal versions your naming of standard functions is unusual,
IMO it should read

```
repeat
  x1 := 2.0 * random - 1.0;
  x2 := 2.0 * random - 1.0;
  w := x1 * x1 + x2 * x2;
until (w<1.0) and (w>0.0);         

w := sqrt(-2.0*ln(w)/w);
result := x1 * w;
ngauss := x2 * w;
```

And note that you really must use `ln` not your self-made base-10 logarithm `log`. The method used is [Marsaglia's polar method.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marsaglia_polar_method)

Comment: Indeed: java's Math.`log` has the natural base e, so already is `ln`.